# API manager, upgrade from 1.4.0 to 1.60

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We're running the WSO2 API Manager 1.4 and would like to upgrade to the latest version 1.6. Can we go directly to 1.6 or do we have to upgrade to 1.5 first? Mainly I'm just concerned regarding the DB migration, as these scripts only seem to be relevant for single version increments. https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/apimgt/1.6.0/modules/distribution/resources/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, for the databases migrations, you can execute [migration-1.4.0_to_1.5.0](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/apimgt/1.6.0/modules/distribution/resources/migration-1.4.0_to_1.5.0/) and [migration-1.5.0_to_1.6.0](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/apimgt/1.6.0/modules/distribution/resources/migration-1.5.0_to_1.6.0/) SQLs sequentially.

It's important to note that API Manager 1.4.0 is based Carbon 4.1.x and API Manager 1.6.0 is based on Carbon 4.2.0. See [Release Matrix for WSO2 Products](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/).

This means that the underlying clustering, registry and user-mgt have some major changes. The API Manager related configurations also has changed.

Therefore my advice is to do as follows.

1. Backup your existing database and API Manager 1.4.0 deployment.
2. Migrate databases in an incremental manner.
3. Re-do all configurations in API Manager 1.6.0 instances. i.e. direct migration from 1.4.0 to 1.6.0. You may compare your API Manager 1.4.0 repository/conf files with a fresh wso2am-1.4.0 pack.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can folow below posts in order. Post [1] provides the migration instructions for wso2 api manager 1.4.0 to 1.5.0. Post [2] provides instructions for migrating from 1.5.0 to 1.6.0.

[1]http://blog.lakmali.com/2013/11/migrating-wso2-api-manager-140-to-150.html
[2]http://blog.lakmali.com/2013/12/migrating-wso2-api-manager-150-to-160.html

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Links were directly providing an answer to question, hence didn't go for describing them. Updated the answer